# How to read from a document file(word,pdf) and insert data into input html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascript, and I noticed in an application that...

1. I uploaded a PDF file
2. it read the file
3. the information on the file was placed into specific html input boxes.

Is this done with javascript and how is it done?

I searched if this topic was already posted, but did not see anything about this. I apologize if there is already a question like this that exists.

Comment: You would need a server side tool to read the word doc or pdf. Apache Tika does this https://tika.apache.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF and DOC files are really complex file types, and reading them require some sort of "engine" capable of doing so. Reading files like HTML and TXT, however, is very simple, but still require a parser so you and your code can "understand" what's really inside the file. It's usually way more than the content you want to get.

Furthermore, most sites today send those uploaded files to the server and read it there, not in the client.

Still, there's a client solution, a library called [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF). It should solve your problem, but like I said, PDFs are complex, so is this library.

Comment: Ahh I see, I see. I guess its time for me to hit the books, thank you so much!